# Why are setters in Grails called twice on save?

Tags: grails, groovy, setter

Look at the following Grails domain class, which modifies a value within a setter, if the object is saved the first time (if it has no id):

```
class Idtest {

  String name

  void setName(String name) {
    if(!this.id)
      this.name = name + "TEST"
    else
      this.name = name
  }

}
```

If I generate views and controller with `generate-all`, start the app, and enter "hello" in the generated form, "helloTESTTEST" is saved.

The `save` function looks like this:

```
def save = {
    def idtestInstance = new Idtest(params)
    if (idtestInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'idtest.label', default: 'Idtest'), idtestInstance.id])}"
        redirect(action: "show", id: idtestInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create", model: [idtestInstance: idtestInstance])
    }
}
```

Why is the setter called twice?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing
    if(!this.id){ }

You should use beforeInsert()

[GORM Advanced Features](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#advancedGORMFeatures)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is called once when you create the object and it is saved

Then it would be called again when you retrieved the object from the database.

So..

On saving to to the database the property is set, lets assume a counter = counter + 1. so now one is saved to the database.

When you retrieve the object from the database, the domain object setter will be called again thereby incrementing the counter again counter++

This is all an assumption since the there is no controller code here for us to see how you are creating and or saving the objects so dont bash me if I am completely off

Comment: It is a good thought that the setter is called again when the object is read from the db, but then the object should have an ID.

Comment: I don't think that the ID is guaranteed to be set before other properties. Apparently, it is not. - BTW, the class does *not* define any constructor that can take named parameters. Internally, the implicit, *nullary* constructor is called, and, after that, the setters are invoked.